# Is there a way to turn categorical variables into a number (R)?

Tags: r, categorical-data, dummy-variable

I have a dataset (imported from Excel) on R, and it has a column for a categorical variable 'sex', with responses male and female, and I would like to change them to 1s and 2s, ie. male=1, and female=2, how could I do this please?
(sidenote: I'm using RStudio)

Comment: `ifelse(df$sex == 'male',1,2)` could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`as.numeric(factor(x))`

Would work. Surely there are many ways to skin this cat.

Better is probably just

`factor(x)`

Though I’m not sure exactly what your next step is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` function, in order to replace a value by another value. Here with 1 or 2 (with "", it will be a character value).

Here an example :

```
x <- c("male", "female", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "male")

x <- replace(x, x=="male", "1")
x <- replace(x, x=="female", "2")

x
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define a customized function and then apply it by using `lapply()`, which does the operation over an specific `df` column:

```
# some random data #
df <- data.frame(sex=c('male', 'female', 'male', 'female'))

encode_fun <- function(x){
 if(x=='female'){
  return(2)
} else if(x=='male'){
  return(1)
} else {
  return(NA)
}
}


df$sex <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df$sex, encode_fun))
```

---

Also, by combining `mutate()` function to perform the conversion and `case_when()` as a function for logical operators from `library(dplyr)`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sex = case_when(sex == 'male' ~ 1,
                          sex == 'female' ~ 2))
```

---

An string approach could be done by using `str_replace()` function from `library(stringr)`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sex = str_replace(sex, '^male', '1')) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sex=str_replace(sex, '^female$', '2')) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(sex = as.numeric(sex))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many ways to do:

```
as.integer(factor(x, levels = c("male", "female")))
```

or

```
c(1, 2)[1 + (x == "female")]
```

or

```
match(x, c("male", "female"))
```

or

```
ifelse(x == "male", 1, 2)
```